# How to create a new thread in WinJS (WinRT)

Tags: windows-runtime, winjs

Is it possible to create a new thread in WinJS? I have to continuously execute a while loop but I do not want it to tie up the UI.

Comment: I think Web Workers are the way to go: http://www.i-programmer.info/ebooks/creating-javascripthtml5-metro-applications/4713-winrt-javascript-web-workers-a-promises.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options:

- WebWorker (as per joe). Getting data in & out of a web worker involves `post/sendMessage`. MSDN Details [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh673568%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).
- If your operation is not javascript specific, You can create a thread in C#/C++, and use that to communicate back to the JavaScript world using WinRT events.